# Cannot escape Insert Mode in ideaVim

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

I am unable to use the `<Esc>` key to leave insert mode and return to Normal Mode. This has 'apparently' happened without any known change, but could be related to a not-so-recent bump of my IntelliJ version (`IntelliJIdea2019.1` -> `IntelliJIdea2019.2`).

One possible solution mentioned online that I tried was to disable, then re-enable ideaVim in `Menu | Tools | Vim emulation`. Trying this did not appear to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it helps in all situations, but what worked for me was just pressing ctrl+c instead of esc (in insert mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing my working `vim_settings.xml` file and broken `vim_settings.xml` file (`~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.1/options/vim_settings.xml`), I noticed the following element:

```xml
<application>
    <component name="VimSettings">
        <state version="4" enabled="false" />
```

I noticed that when running:

`watch "head ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.1/options/vim_settings.xml"`

This file **did not** update. This was not something I would of expected, so I updated the file manually.

The manually change to this file, changing `enabled="false"` to `enabled="true"`, fixed this issue for me.

I think this could be a bug related to IdeaVim, but it could even be IntelliJ and happening elsewhere?

Comment: This is not a bug, you've just accordingly disabled vim emulation. See the answer.

Comment: See changes, updated as this answer is found all over the internet, but did not fix the issue in my specific case.

Comment: Do you mean that `enabled="false"` is not updated after you toggle `tools | Vim emulator`? The files in `options` folders are updated not immediately, but only in some specific cases like IJ instance close, or pressing `apply` button in settings.

Comment: That was the behaviour I was seeing, yes. I'm 99% certain I restarted IJ, but even so it was an issue for me for a number of days, so I was playing with settings a fair bit and I'm sure I toggled IdeaVim off and on a number of times over that period. I've now found that following my manual change, I cannot replicate the issue, so cannot be 100% certain this was happening.

Answer (score 3):

Vim mode for IntelliJ IDEA can be toggled via the `Menu | Tools | Vim emulation` option.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good point and a suggestion I found a lot online. I've updated the question and answer to include the fact that it was something I tried and it did not solve the issue in my specific case.

Answer (score 3):

`ctrl+c` worked for me on windows. I was not able to see "vim emulator" in Help->Find Action

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to remove the ESC button, assigned to Switch Focus To Editor.

Settings -> Keymap -> Terminal, Switch Focus To Editor -> remove
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Just press the insert key on your keyboard.